# Rails model test always allow non-nullable column to be null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, schema

I have a schema:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      # Username cannot be null
      t.string :username, null: false
      t.string :password, null: false
      t.string :email, null: false
      t.integer :health_record
      t.boolean :admin, default: false
      t.boolean :activated, default: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And I tried to run the following test:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    @user = User.new(username: 'Bob', password: 'h1l34asi', email: 'loyu@kbu.edu')
  end

  test 'user creation' do
    assert @user.valid?
  end

  test 'user creation with no username' do
    @user.username = nil
    # This assertion won't pass!
    assert @user.invalid?
  end
end
```

But I always get this error:

```
Failure:
UserTest#test_user_creation_with_no_username [/project/test/models/user_test.rb:15]:
Expected true to be nil or false
```

I've tried the following before the test:

```
rails db:migrate
rails db:reset
rails db:migrate:reset
```

[And my sqlite db looks fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zw4i9.png).

But it still doesn't work. Why?

Answer (score 1):

`null: false` constraint works on `DB` level. You will get an error when trying to save the record in DB, but on the `Model` level the instance is valid despite the `username` is `nil`.

You should add validation:

```
class User < ApllicationRecord
  validates :username, presence: true
  # ...
end
```